# How to remove only the first <h3> from an html string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I have an html string and I need to remove only the first `<h3>` tag.

I tried the code below but removes all `<h3>` tags

```
$final = preg_replace('#<h3>(.*?)</h3>#', '', $html);
echo $final;
```

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regexes.

Answer (score 1):

just RTM
http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php
Add the 4th argument to preg_replace

```
<?php
$html = '
<h3>one</h3>
<h3>two</h3>
<h3>tree</h3>
zzz
';
$final = preg_replace('#<h3>(.*?)</h3>#', '', $html, 1);
echo $final;
```

Tested on http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point is always the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). If you take a look there, you will see that the fourth (optional) argument to `preg_replace()` is the number of replacements to make. I think adding that to your function call should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Per http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php, an optional parameter limits the number of replacements performed. I think you want this:

```
 $final = preg_replace('#<h3>(.*?)</h3>#', '', $html, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way would be using `strpos` and `substr` functions:

```
// exemplary string
$htmlStr = 'some text ...<h3>some header</h3>'
        . '<div class="content">text content</div><h3>another header</h3>';

$first_pos = strpos($htmlStr, "<h3");  // the position of the opening tag
$last_pos = strpos($htmlStr, "</h3>"); // // the position of the closing tag
$final = substr($htmlStr, 0, $first_pos) . substr($htmlStr, $last_pos + 5);

print_r($final);
// will output 'some text ...<div class="content">text content</div><h3>another header</h3>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this a good example to use a parser instead?
Consider this and see [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/lJEiFE):

```
<?php

$html = <<<DATA
<h3>First header</h3>
<p>Some other stuff here</p>
<h3>Another header1</h3>
<p>Some other stuff here</p>
DATA;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

// get first headeline
$headers = $dom->getElementsByTagName('h3')->item(0);
if ($header) $header->parentNode->removeChild($header);

// make sure it worked
echo $dom->saveHTML();

?>
```